# Hide a graph conditionally

Tags: gnuplot

I want to hide the corresponding graph if a specific parameter is given. But I still want to draw other plots. I'm simply making the calculations incorrect (division by 0) but it still appears in the key.

```
set terminal png size 800,640
set output "test.png"
set xrange [0:70000]
set yrange [0:2500]
G=6.674*10**-11
M=5.2915793*10**22
R=600000.0
if (!exists('sma')) {
  sma=-R
}
set key right bottom
plot sqrt((250*G*M)/((R+x)**2*1.2230948554874*exp(-x/5000)*0.2)) title 'Terminal' with lines, \
     sqrt(G*M*(2/(x+R)-1/(sma+R)))-174.53 title 'Orbital' with lines
```

I also tried to move the if condition within the plot command but as expected it didn't work, because of `undefined function: if`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no generic way to hide an plot which is completely undefined. The command

```
plot 1/0
```

aborts with an error, but

```
plot x, 1/0
```

plots `x` but adds a key entry for both plots.

In your case you can check the value of `(sma + R)` and set the title accordingly:

```
plot sqrt((250*G*M)/((R+x)**2*1.2230948554874*exp(-x/5000)*0.2)) title 'Terminal' with lines, \
     sqrt(G*M*(2/(x+R)-1/(sma+R)))-174.53 title ((sma + R) == 0 ? '' : 'Orbital') with lines
```